# UWP Set NavigationView TogglePaneButton color

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, navigationview

As you can see from the image, the `TogglePaneButton` has a distinct color from the remaining.

[image]

That's because I set it manually to `WhiteSmoke` (actually in my pushed code it's already gray) when it is in the `LeftMinimal` mode in its source code of `VisualState` Compact.

[image]

I thought I could change it back when pane is open by modifying its visual state like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="RootSplitView.PaneBackground" Value="{ThemeResource MainNavigationViewBackground}" />
        <Setter Target="TogglePaneButton.Background" Value="{ThemeResource MainNavigationViewBackground}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

But it is not working. How can I achieve that?

The code has exceeded 30000 characters so I can only post the link:

https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Dictionaries/MainNavigationView.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very simple solution:

Just make another `TogglePaneButton` and put it over the original one. Then let it work as the real one. Set its visibility to `Collapsed` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `VisualStates` react to the different types of the pane modes, but do not react to the open/closed event.

I would recommend giving the button itself a `Transparent` background and just displaying a colored `Border` under the button and pane. When the pane will be closed and in minimal mode, the border under the button will make it look as if the button had the right background color. When the pane opens, it will be drawn *above* the `Border`, and the button will have the same background as the pane.

Comment: What's the background of border?

Comment: The `Border` should have the background of the "tab bar" - so `WhiteSmoke`

Comment: The problem is that, I have a `WhiteSmoke` title bar only when the `NavigationView` is `LeftMinimal`. How do I make it transparent when it is not? Actually, I am mimicking Groove Music, from which you can see this behavior.

Comment: I think you could use Adaptive triggers to show the Border only for the appropriate Window size. Alternatively, you could use the Pane Opening or Opened event to hide/show it, but that is less XAML-only solution :-)